# How to translate custom pipes in angular using i18n?

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization

I am translating my Angular 7 app using i18n and I have custom pipes that produce text. How can I translate the text produced by the pipes?

I stick to the [i18n guideline](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) provided by the angular docs, I use this [xliff merge strategy](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/wiki/Tutorial-for-using-xliffmerge-with-angular-cli) for development and I use [this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-implement-localization-in-angular-using-i18n-tools-a88898b1a0d0) for my builds per locale.

For example, I am trying to translate this [time ago pipe](https://github.com/AndrewPoyntz/time-ago-pipe/blob/master/time-ago.pipe.ts) in which numbers are converted to text.

At the moment I have no idea how to translate custom pipes. I only know how to translate html tags using the `i18n` attribute, which does not seem to be applicable to the custom pipes that I use.

This [angular i18n paragraph](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes) suggests to set a some kind of global variable in the main `app.module.ts`, but the examples are a bit scarce and (a) I don't know how to set the locale depending on the build per language as I do following [this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-implement-localization-in-angular-using-i18n-tools-a88898b1a0d0), (b) I don't know how to get the global locale into my custom pipe and (c) is it possible translate the contents for the pipe in the `messages.<locale>.xlf` files instead of within the pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Usually what you can do in this situation, is add the translateService as a dependency into your pipe, and just translate from code.

So your constructor in the pipe would look like:

```js
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private ngZone: NgZone, private tr: TranslateService) {}
```

And in your transform function you can return the text value with this:

```js
// [...]
} else if (days <= 545) {
  return this.tr.instant('time.one-year-ago');
} else { // (days > 545)
  return this.tr.instant('time.years-ago', { years });
}
// [...]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Coo! I think using a pipe translation service will be unavoidable. Still, I prefer to have all translations in one place but that does not seem practical. Will let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: My suggested solution allows you to still keep your translations in one place!

Comment: TranslateService doesnt seem to be the solution, as this service ist not part of Angular but a 3rd party module (ngx-translate). I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: You could have your pipes return the normal text or translation strings, and still have the i18 attribute in your template. e.g.: `<h1 i18n>{{ some.data | myCustomPipe }}</h1>`. Does that fit your needs?